# What is the best way to load fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments in which i am showing webview, so keeping it simple, what is best way to load fragments? I want to load fragments in a way that they don't take up large amount of resources while loading, and keeping a low footprint in ram.

I am using these two techniques. Please guide me which one is more efficient? And if you have any better alternative please i like to know.

Fragment A:

```
public class example
        extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    View myUIUpdate2(View view) {
        // some stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible_) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(true);

        if(this.isVisible()) {
            // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
            if(isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) {
                myUIUpdate2(getView());
                _hasLoadedOnce = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Fragment B:

```
public class example
        extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myUIUpdate(view);
    }

    void myUIUpdate(View view) {
        //some stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible_) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        if(this.isVisible()) {
            // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
            if(isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) {
                myUIUpdate2(getView());
                _hasLoadedOnce = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

In which way fragment will be more efficient?

Comment: You're showing 3 WebViews which on Lollipop and above is based on Chromium, you shouldn't expect it to have a low RAM footprint.

Comment: Then what should be the approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference between using onCreateView or onViewCreated in terms of efficiency because they are both called by the Fragment life cycle whether or not you override them.

Therefore,  in the larger scheme of things, you're over thinking the optimization

Comment: `There is little difference between using onCreateView or onViewCreated`. There is actually a difference: `onCreateView()` fires **during** the View creation, onViewCreated()` fires **after** the View creation.

Comment: @BobMalooga In the context of the question, there is no *efficiency* difference. Suppose I should have been more clear on that

Comment: I don't know if there is an improvement in terms of speed in preferring one or the other. I didn't test that.

Comment: @BobMalooga I haven't ran performance benchmarks or anything (also, not sure how to go about that), I'm just saying in one case the view is created and in the other, it isn't. In any case, the logic around finding the views and updating them remains a constant factor